# Android ratings and listviews

Tags: android, android-listview

I'd like to add a list of reviews of books to my Android app. Basically what I'm after is a fixed rating using the RatingBar and a ListView containing the snippet of the review for each review. Once clicked I want the list item to expand and fill with the text of the full review.

I have the content of the snippet, full text, and rating, but don't know how best to go about the layout. Any ideas are ok, I don't need full code, but I would much prefer to keep it to XML layout.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just extended an Adapter, obvious answer.

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/